# hardcoded Hero slides to gatsby-image-plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

My "Home hero slide" is the last hardcoded part of my site. I want to make it dynamic and use the magic of gatsby-image-plugin.

[my site link](https://awesome-joliot-d12da0.netlify.app/)

the "hardcoded" codes:

HeroSlider.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useInterval } from './useInterval'
import Hero1 from '../../images/hero1.webp'
import Hero2 from '../../images/hero2.webp'
import Hero3 from '../../images/hero4.webp'

const HeroSlider = () => {

  const slides = [
    {
      id: '01',
      image: Hero1
    },
    {
      id: '02',
      image: Hero2
    },
    {
      id: '03',
      image: Hero3
    }
  ]

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    slides,
    activeIndex: 0,
    autoSlide: true,
    interval: 3000
  })

  // By Dan Abramov overreacted.io
  useInterval(
    () => {
      setState(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        activeIndex: (prev.activeIndex + 1) % prev.slides.length
      }))
    },
    state.autoSlide ? state.interval : null
  )

  return (
    <SliderWrapper>
      {slides.map((slide, i) => (
        <Slide key={slide.id} slide={slide} active={state.activeIndex === i} />
      ))}
    </SliderWrapper>
  )
}

export default HeroSlider
```

HeroSlider.styles.js

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const StyledImg = styled.div`
  background: ${props =>
    `linear-gradient(
      to bottom, rgba(32, 33, 35, .8)
      39%,rgba(32, 33, 35, .8)
      41%,rgba(32, 33, 35, .8)
      100%
    ),
    url('${props.image}'), var(--darkGrey)`};
```

Slide.js

```js
import React from 'react'

import { StyledImg, WbnSlide } from './HeroSlider.styles'

const Slide = ({ slide, active }) => (
  <WbnSlide className={active ? 'active' : ''}>
  
  
  <StyledImg image={slide.image} />
   
   
   <div className="wbn-overlay-text">
      <h1 className="wbn-header">Desenvolvimento Front End</h1>
      <p className="wbn-text">
        A mágica do React em suas aplicações com performance e design incríveis,
        para voce alcançar seus objetivos de negócio.
        <button type="button" className="sldie-button">
          <span>COMECE AGORA</span> entre em contato
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </WbnSlide>
)

export default Slide
```

I'm querying the ACF that I created to add the images to the slide:

```js
query HomeSlidesQuery {
  wpPage(databaseId: {eq: 13}) {
    id
    ACF_HomePage {
      slideimages {
        slide {
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(formats: WEBP, layout: FULL_WIDTH, placeholder: BLURRED)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That returns an array:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "wpPage": {
      "id": "cG9zdDoxMw==",
      "ACF_HomePage": {
        "slideimages": [
          {
            "slide": {
              "localFile": {
                "childImageSharp": {
                  "gatsbyImageData": {
                    "layout": "fullWidth",
                    "placeholder": {
                      "fallback":
```

I don't know how to use this data to replace my hardcoded array and the props in styled component "StyledImg". I tried several approaches but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something this should work:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useInterval } from './useInterval'
import Hero1 from '../../images/hero1.webp'
import Hero2 from '../../images/hero2.webp'
import Hero3 from '../../images/hero4.webp'

const HeroSlider = ({data}) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    data.wpPage.ACF_HomePage.slideimages,
    activeIndex: 0,
    autoSlide: true,
    interval: 3000
  })

  // By Dan Abramov overreacted.io
  useInterval(
    () => {
      setState(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        activeIndex: (prev.activeIndex + 1) % prev.slides.length
      }))
    },
    state.autoSlide ? state.interval : null
  )

  return (
    <SliderWrapper>
      {data.wpPage.ACF_HomePage.slideimages.map({slide}, i) => (
        <Slide key={i} slide={slide} active={state.activeIndex === i} />
      ))}
    </SliderWrapper>
  )
}


query HomeSlidesQuery {
  wpPage(databaseId: {eq: 13}) {
    id
    ACF_HomePage {
      slideimages {
        slide {
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(formats: WEBP, layout: FULL_WIDTH, placeholder: BLURRED)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


export default HeroSlider
```

Then, following the structure you are querying:

```
import React from 'react'

import { StyledImg, WbnSlide } from './HeroSlider.styles'

const Slide = ({ slide, active }) => {
 console.log("slide data", slide);

 return <WbnSlide className={active ? 'active' : ''}>
  
  
  <StyledImg image={slide.localFile.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} />
   
   
   <div className="wbn-overlay-text">
      <h1 className="wbn-header">Desenvolvimento Front End</h1>
      <p className="wbn-text">
        A mágica do React em suas aplicações com performance e design incríveis,
        para voce alcançar seus objetivos de negócio.
        <button type="button" className="sldie-button">
          <span>COMECE AGORA</span> entre em contato
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </WbnSlide>
}

export default Slide
```

Assuming that your queries retrieve the proper data, you only need to loop through the slides (`slideimages`). I destructured the nested `slide` but the idea is the same. Then you only need to know what your styled-component is receiving via props for each `slide` in the `Slide` component (where I placed a `console.log()`).

Check the `useInterval` hook to be sure that the states are properly set because your data structure may have changed. Notice also that you don't have the `id` now, you may want to include it somehow in your WordPress, for now, I've used the index (`i`) as a `key` for each `slide`.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply Ferran! I'm going to have to think a little bit here about how to use these tips.